# Why can't i access method from another class but can access variable?

Tags: java, android, class, object, methods

I have two classes named abc and def. Class abc has string named "paths" and function named "test". I can easily use the variable "paths" from another class "def" but can't seem to call the function "test" from class "def".

I have created an object of class abc in class def and tried to call the function but it doesn't work.

```
public class abc extends Activity {
    String paths="path";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        test("lol");
    }
    public void test(String name){
        Toast.makeText(abc.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public class def extends Activity {
abc x= new abc();
String paths=x.paths;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(def.this,paths,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// This is 
    //working
    x.test("hahahas"); // Not working
    }
}
```

i want the method "test" from class abc to be used by class def passing parameter from class def.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: Did you mean to have `def` extend `abc` and `x.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`  ?

Comment: I am developing an android app. It says app has stopped working.

Comment: Unrelated: class names go UpperCamelCase in Java.

Comment: Define "Not working", precisely. Not that the instruction that is working is creating a Toast with the **current** activity (`def.this,`which could just be `this`), whereas the one that is not working is creating a Toast with a separate, unrelated activity (`abc.this`)

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Learn how to get to your log file. I would guess that some variable is null and your app crashes due to a nullpointer exception.

Comment: Check the logcat

Comment: You do realize that `paths` data member in class `def` is _hiding_ data member of same name in class `abc`, right?

Comment: @JBNizet Even after i changed (`abc.this`) to `.this`, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Of course, since `abc.this` is strictly identical to `this`. I'm not an Android expert, but I don't think it makes any sense to pass another, unrelated activity you created yourself when creating a toast. Why are you doing that?

Comment: This question is so weird, you're trying to have two Activity living at the same time, and we can't know in which package they are (they need to be in different files, 'def' isn't an inner class), neither the log messages (so the error's cause). So my answer is: the error could be in the fact that 'abc' and 'def' are two activities: do you really need two activities?

Comment: @LucaMurra They are in different files. "def"class is not the child class of class "abc".

Comment: Sure, but the question is still alive: do you really need two activities?

Comment: @LucaMurra Yes i do need two classes. The concept of base and derived class makes it clear. I need to use the function from the base class repeatedly.

Comment: You can have as many classes as you want, but you can't have two activities living together, but maybe I misunderstood something

Comment: @LucaMurra class abc exists in another file and def exists in another file if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments. I found the solution. In class def, instead of extending Activity i used

`public class def extends abc`

making class "def" child class of "abc". And after the line

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

in class "def" i added one line shown below which did the job.

`super.test("lol123");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this

```
abc x= new abc();
```

You shouldn't be creating an instance of something that extends `Activity` in this way. You should be using `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`

Also, you shouldn't be holding a reference to one activity inside an instance of another one at all, because activities are created and destroyed by Android so the reference you hold to it may go stale. See [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)`. Simply rotating your device is enough to make this happen.

From the tutorial "build your first app" we have [start another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity), assuming that you do infact want to launch another activity. You need to learn about intents; let me quote from that link:

> An Intent is an object that provides runtime binding between separate components, such as two activities. The Intent represents an app’s "intent to do something."

Comment: Since i am new to Java can you please explain how can i use `startActivity` in this case.

Comment: I've added another link. It seems the problem is not so much that you're new to Java but that you're new to Android - please try the beginners' tutorials.

Comment: You are right, the problem is small but I have been stuck on this for like hours. Thank you for the link, I'll check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Are the classes in the same package? (I assumeing that they are in the same package, because you dont have public infront of `String paths`)

If a method is public you should be able to call it from everywhere.
So i guess you have a problem in your test case.
try with classes, that do not extend `Activity` and only have the methods needed to test. Then extend your testcase further and further until it stops working.

Is the path variable final?
you might want to add `public static final` modifier to it.